# allowed parents property is not working in adobe cq

Tags: adobe, aem

Hi i have created two components in adobe c.q_5 for example component_1 and component_2. i want that component_2 can be use only under component_1 for that i use a property allowed parents its value is */component_1. but it is not working can anybody help me.

```
allowedParents
String[]
*/component_1



3
cq:lastReplicated
Date
2013-08-23T17:00:30.726+05:30
false
false
false
false
4
cq:lastReplicatedBy
String
admin
false
false
false
false
5
cq:lastReplicationAction
String
Activate
false
false
false
false
6
jcr:created
Date
2013-08-23T20:03:22.437+05:30
true
false
false
true
7
jcr:createdBy
String
admin
true
false
false
true
8
jcr:mixinTypes
Name[]
cq:ReplicationStatus
true
false
true
false
9
jcr:primaryType
Name
cq:Component
true
true
false
true
10
jcr:title
String
AIB Thumbnail
false
false
false
false
11
sling:resourceSuperType
String
foundation/components/parbase
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: Is component 1 a container ? When you say it is not working, what kind of behavior are you actually experiencing ? Please provide these info.

Comment: basically its a accordion component i want to restrict that the accordion entry component drag and drop only in accordion no where else. i am sending you the link of component  http://jenikya.com/blog/2012/03/cq5-accordion-component.html

Comment: Have you made sure you have modified the appropriate properties in the parsys component and the the accordion component, specifically the allowedChildren, allowedParents etc. ? I also suggest that you update your question with the implementation / properties of your container component (accordion), entry component (accordion entry) and the parsys component. Also please post the details as an xml instead of copying the entire contents as above, as an xml might help in analysing it better.

Comment: I'm also finding that the allowedParents property doesn't work (AEM 6)